# PHP. Первый скрипт и маленькая проблема.

Tags: xml, php

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь написать свой **первый сценарий на PHP** и нуждаюсь совета.

Пишу парсер youtube канала который является xml документом.

Он извлекает    заголовок, id и дату видео и    записывает их в базу данных.

И и так    для нескольких страниц.
**Так в чем же проблема?**

1. Цикл проходит точное количество раз и записывает в базу все верно, но только из первого документа, то есть дублирует записи. Мои предположения что объект **new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);** записывается единожди для всех циклов. Как это исправить? Чтобы проход был по всем документам?
2. Меня терзают смутные сомнения по применению **preg_match all** для извлечения id видео. Как-то не очень хочется работать с вложенными массивами. Прошу проверки и нравоучений.

Спасибо за внимание.

```
   for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
 echo "<strong>".$i.".Страница</strong></br>";
    $homepage = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/1tv/uploads?orderby=published&max-results=5&start-index=".$i);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
{

    $title = (string)$entry->title;
    echo $title."</br>";

}
}
```

Comment: там строки типа http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EyrYTCv1nfU нужно 
EyrYTCv1nfU ?

Comment: почему-бы не сделать `preg_match('([\w-]{11})',((string)$entry->id), $id);` ($id - массив значение в $id[0])

Comment: тут

     $title = $entry->title;

лучше писать

     $title = (string)$entry->title;

чтобы точно задать тип.

Comment: вот это показывает разные значения.

    <?php
     for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
     echo "------------\n";
        $homepage = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/1tv/uploads?orderby=published&max-results=50&start-index=".$i);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);

    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
    {
        $e=(string)$entry->id;
        preg_match('([\w-]{11})',$entry->id, $id);
        echo("{$id[0]}\n");

    }
    }

Comment: спасибо за ваши ответы. Проблема с дублированием осталась. Никак не могу понять как проходит по циклам и почему присутствуют повторения. Для наглядности изменил код:

<?php
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
echo "<strong>".$i.".Страница</strong></br>";
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/1tv/uploads?orderby=published&max-results=5&start-index=".$i);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
{
 
 $title = (string)$entry->title;
    echo $title."</br>";

}
} ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты, видимо, неверно понял систему запросов. URL вида `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/1tv/uploads?orderby=published&`**max-results=5**`&`**start-index=$i** имеет 3 параметра, 2 из которых важны в этом случае.

`max-results` определяет, сколько записей будет содержать ответ,
а `start-index` — это не номер *не страницы, а записи* (от 1). То есть, если в первый раз ты получил 3 записи, то в следующем запросе нужно подставлять не `start-index=2`, а `start-index=4`.

```
$pages = 5;
$items_per_page = 3;

for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++)
    {
    echo "<strong>".$i.". Страница</strong></br>";
    $homepage = file_get_contents(
        "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/1tv/uploads?orderby=published".
        "&max-results=".$items_per_page.
        "&start-index=".($i * $items_per_page + 1)
        );

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);
    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
        {
        $title = (string)$entry->title;
        echo $title."</br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот-вот. Только хотел написать об этом. И в самом деле проблема была с читаемостью этих страниц, а именно в start-index.
Большое спасибо за вашу помощь и потраченное время.

Comment: можно узнать каким текстовым редактором вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Вообще я пользуюсь notepad++, но конкретно этот код писал в редакторе ACEeditor на koding.com. На нормальную IDE никак не получается перейти :)